# How can I get this column layout using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm struggling to get a specific column width using Bootstrap columns.

https://www.codeply.com/p/SSBBdBMXNc:
[image]

From the above, I want to maintain the label column width but the textbox column needs to extend all the way to the end.

**UPDATE:**
To be more clear:
[image]

Simply switching from col 5 to 12 also increases the width of label:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating my own custom classes for the desired widths I required.

Relative to the bootstrap column layouts 1 - 12, the widths I needed worked out to 1.6644 and 10.3356.

```css
.col-1_6644,
.col-10_3356 {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.col-1_6644 {
    width: 13.87%;
}

.col-10_3356 {
    width: 86.13%;
}
```

https://codeply.com/p/SSBBdBMXNc

Answer (score 3):

you have added class="col-lg-5"

you should try something like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">label</div>
            <div class="col-lg-8">textbox</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I've added more info to the question

Comment: then you need to change the grid width from class="col-lg-4" to class="col-lg-2"  and class="col-lg-8" to class="col-lg-10".

Answer (score 1):

Here you go...

You need to change `<div class="col-lg-5">` to `<div class="col-lg-12">` if you want to achieve this. You might be confused because 4 columns + 8 columns = 12 columns, but these two elements will not take full-window width because they are limited with `<div class="col-lg-5">`.

###### UPDATE

HTML:

```
<br />
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2" id="label">label</div>
        <div class="col-lg" id="textbox">textbox</div>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
```

CSS:

```
div:not(.row) {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    #label {
        width: 13vw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I've updated the question with a screenshot illustrating the desired look.
I know how the column system (1-12) works but simply switching from 5 to 12 means the label column width also increases which I want to maintain.

Comment: I expect additional rows/cols for the desired look but just not sure how to get it myself

Comment: I updated my answer. What about now?

Comment: Thanks. I've had a look and it seems like the label column still doesn't match.
I've ended up creating a custom col class for the desired effect. https://www.codeply.com/p/SSBBdBMXNc

Comment: If you want something really specific (I would say you do), then this is probably the best option.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove that first `col` and the second `row` completely if you wanted to, like this.

```
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4">label</div>
      <div class="col-lg-8">textbox</div>
  </div>
```

You can also put all that in a `container` to finish it off nicely..... Worth noting that if you use `container-fluid` instead it will be more of a full screen width rather than a thinner container centered in the screen. If you don't use a container at all, everything above will be at the edges of your screen.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4">label</div>
      <div class="col-lg-8">textbox</div>
   </div>
</div>
```